# Can't Recreate Values for U, S, V from SVD in numpy

Tags: linear-algebra, svd, numpy

To better understand SVD, I'm trying to recreate the values for `U`, `S`, and `V` using straight numpy, but I can't get the same results.

According to numpy's [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html) for its implementation of SVD, it returns values for `U`, `S`, and `V` such that you can recreate your original dataset in the following way:

```
(U*S) @ V = original_data
```

My understanding is that the values for `U` are derived from the eigenvectors of $ XX^T $, `V` from the eigenvectors of $X^TX$, and they share the same eigenvalues, and their square root comprise the values for `S`.

So, to recreate these on my own I'm doing the following:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
boston = load_boston()
X = boston.data
u_vals, u_vecs = np.linalg.eig(X.dot(X.T))
v_vals, v_vecs = np.linalg.eig(X.T.dot(X))
```

My thinking is that `u_vecs[:, :13] @ np.diag(v_vals**.5) @ v_vecs.T` ought to do the trick.

However, this gives very different results.

Even more, I've checked further, and the only difference between the values I have from numpy's eigensolver and the ones returned from its `svd` method are the signs involved in the eigenvectors used.

However, my (perhaps naive) understanding is that this shouldn't make a difference.  However, I'm clearly mistaken in something.

Is it simply a case of using a different eigensolver, or is there a deeper misunderstanding that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1805191/339790).